# Open a PDF document on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

is UIWebView the only way to open a pdf document on the iphone? how can i interact with the document? eg: getting the current page number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read the Apple documentation about Drawing with quartz 2d. There's a section just about handling with PDF documents.
If you don't like to show a PDF in a UIWebView, you create your own view. Just subclass UIView and overwrite the method `-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect` for your custom drawing. Create a CGContextRef a draw your PDF directly in that context using the specific function of core graphics. Core Graphics provides a lot of other functions for PDF documents, like Kalle already mentioned.

If you're not really used to core graphics, it's really difficult sometimes and you probably need a lot time to get used to it, so I recommend using UIWebView to display a PDF. It relatively simple.

Comment: do you have a link to apple's documentation page?

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 0):

It's not the only way. There's a whole toolkit built in which lets you render PDF pages to a UIView. Check out:

- CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL
- CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages
- CGPDFDocumentGetPage
- CGContextDrawPDFPage

to name a few (core graphics) functions that relate to PDF rendering.

Answer (score 0):

Check Apple's ZoomingPDFViewer for a simple example: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ZoomingPDFViewer/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score 0):

Beside UIWebView, if you want a high level interaction class, check out: [UIDocumentInteractionController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDocumentInteractionController_class/Reference/Reference.html), [QLPreviewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/QLPreviewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Depending on your needs, check out the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3950402/272342) to this question.