# Add navigationbar or back-button in PDF, cordova

Tags: ios, cordova

I created an iOS app that displays me a page(view). Whenever I try to click on a PDF, it opens and I can see it but I don't have any Back-button or a navigationbar to get out from PDF, and get back into my app. I don't want to use my home button, and to close my app. Is this even possible, somehow? Used cordova to build the app.

Comment: Are you clicking on a pdf from a view in your app, or are you clicking on a pdf in Finder?

Comment: I'm opening, my app. This app displays me a page -> from example google. If i'm trying to click on a PDF, it opens but i don't have any button or navigation bar to go back to my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are opening a pdf from your app, you are somewhere in a view that is showing you the pdf-document. This view is managed by a view controller. In your storyboard you can select on the view controller that either shows you the pdf document or the view controller that shows you the pdf document. This view controller can then be embedded in a navigation controller. You dod this by going to the menu, click editor->embed in->Navigation controller.

Your views will then automatically get a back button to jump back to the previous view controller if there was a previous view controller.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think i know what you are saying, but !. Hmm, i dont wan't to use window.open(targetFile, _blank, 'toolbar=YES') to open a toolbar on bottom of my view. with back+forward button, and close button. I want to have a toolbard, on top of my view, only in PDF, if it's possible with a back button, kinda something like: https://www.raymondcamden.com/2016/06/26/linking-to-pdfs-in-cordova-apps. Thank you.

Comment: As far as I can see it, the back button in the linked article is a standard back button from the view controller. When you only embed the view controller that opens the pdf document in a navigation controller, only this view controller will get the back button at the top, just like in the linked article. If you need to do it in Cordova as a Webview, I can't help you.

Comment: Have another question... is it possible, somehow, when i try to open pdf in viewbrowser, to ask me before, how do i want to open it (with safari or pdf reader installed app - for example) ?

Comment: Can you, please, look at this answer? Opening pdf-documents is been answered more than once. For that, you don't need cordova. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3950313/open-a-pdf-document-on-iphone